# Is %dn a format string?

Tags: c, printf, format-string

I recently came across this line in a code  -

```
fprintf(logfile,"   |-IP Version        : %dn",(unsigned int)iph->version);
```

Is "%dn" here a format string ? If so , what does it signify ?

Comment: Throughout the code , all fprintf's had the same %dn , which made me wonder if someone would make the same mistake more than once.. please chk the following link and let me know .. And thanks for your responses .

http://www.binarytides.com/blog/packet-sniffer-code-in-c-using-linux-sockets-bsd/

Comment: Carl is right, the blog probably consumed the backslashes. Funny.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds a bit like someone wanted to write `%d\n` to terminate the line with a linefeed, but the backslash got lost somewhere. The format code, in any case, ends with the "d".

Answer (score 5):

No, %d is a format string, signifying decimal value. 'n' will be appended. Unless it's '\n', which it probably is supposed to be, which is a newline (which will also be appended of course).

Answer (score 1):

It signifies a decimal number followed by a character `'n'`.